# There's something clogging up my Startup Disk space, I can't find it even using Disk Inventory X

Tags: macos, storage

[image: Storrage]

For some reason there's something clogging up my Startup Disk space. I can't find it even using Disk Inventory X.

Comment: To free up some space, I'd start with turning off MobileBackups.  See: [What Crap Is This: OS X's MobileBackups](https://classicyuppie.com/what-crap-is-this-os-xs-mobilebackups/)

Comment: What does Disk Inventory X show for free space? 750.3 MB?  Have you tried one of the other disk space apps?  I personally find Disk Inventory X's display hard to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how to use Terminal ? 
You could install this:
https://github.com/wvangeit/duk
by executing 'pip install duk' using the Terminal.
Then execute 'sudo duk /', and it will show you the space usage on your disk.